# linear transformation question help needed

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

i am utterly lost, im having trouble with linear transformations

let $T : P2 → P2$ given by $T(p(x)) = p(1) + 4x · p'(x)$ and let

$B = {1 + x, x + x^2, 1 + x^2}, C = {1, x, x^2}$
be bases for P2.
(C is the standard basis. Also, p'(x) denotes the derivative of the polynomial p(x).)

(a) Show that T is a linear transformation.
(b) Compute [T]C,B. (it is [T] subscript c,b
(c) Compute [T]B,C.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this MathJax tutorial and rewrite your question: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. Besides that, what have you tried? Do you know the definition of a linear transformation? Do you know what you have to show in order to prove that $T$ is a lin.tr? Where are you having trouble?

Answer (score 0):

$$Hint$$

See at first what is the definition of linear transformation.

Then just put $p(x)=1$, $p(x)=x$, $p(x)=x^2$. & Express each of this as linear combination of $1, x,x^2$ first. Try to form the matrix. Thus you will $[T]_C^C$. Now try to express each of this as linear combination of $1+x, x+x^2 ,1+x^2$. Try to form the matrix. Thus you will $[T]_C^B$. Now try c) by yourself.